# SQL Server msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail, If the file size is above 3mb then that attachment is not being sent

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I am sending email in SQL Server 20012 using `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` for sending email.

Everything is working fine till "file_attachments" size is 3 MB. If the file size is above then that attachment is not going.

Please help how can I send file size between 5-10 MB.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
       @recipients = @EMailid,
       @copy_recipients = @CCMailid,
       @blind_copy_recipients = @CCEMail,
       @body = @NewStrHtmlDetail,--- Body
       @subject = @Subject,
       @body_format = 'HTML',
       @file_attachments = @file_attachments,  ---@file_attachments please add file location name
       @profile_name = 'Emamigroup';
```

Comment: can you post what does `dbo.sysmail_event_log` say

Comment: also look out this answer on why this appears to be big:https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143779/maximum-attachment-size-in-database-mail

Comment: This error is coming. File attached or query result size exceeds allowable value of 1000000 bytes.

Comment: The default DB mail attachment size was changed. but still facing same issue.

Comment: what is the issue,what does mail error log say

Answer (score 2):

According to [sp_send_dbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql)  default value is one MB. You need to change it:

> [ @file_attachments= ] 'file_attachments'
>
> Is a semicolon-delimited list of file names to attach to the e-mail message. Files in the list must be specified as absolute paths. The attachments list is of type nvarchar(max). **By default, Database Mail limits file attachments to 1 MB per file.**

SSMS -> Management -> Mail -> Configuration Wizard

There will be field: "Maximum File Size (bytes)"

More info [Configure Database Mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/configure-database-mail).

Comment: The default DB mail attachment size was changed. but still facing the same issue "attachment not coming in email"

Comment: @TripurariYadav How do you send emails(SQL Server job)? Maybe you need to restart SQL Server Agent to apply this changes

Comment: I tried to invoke that procedure manually, but the attachment is not received.